# Get week ranges for documents

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm trying to get unique date ranges by week for all records. I want to allow users to be able to get a set of records between `mm-dd-yyyy - mm-dd-yyyy`, as shown here:

[image]

**Schema snippet:**

```
var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        date: Date, //ISO formatted date
```

**Query:** I am trying to use `aggregate` to format the ISO dates.

```
    var query = Order.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $project:
                {
                    year:
                    {
                        $year: '$date'
                    },
                    month:
                    {
                        $month: '$date'
                    },
                    day:
                    {
                        $dayOfMonth: '$date'
                    },
                    week:
                    {
                        $week: '$date'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group:
                {
                    _id: null,
                    distinctDate:
                    {
                        $addToSet:
                        {
                            year: '$year',
                            month: '$month',
                            day: '$day',
                            week: '$week'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    );
```

**Result:** This seems to give me unique dates for each record:

[image]

So then I formatted it to look like above. Unfortunately, the results don't seem to match up, are out of order.

```
        res.data[0].distinctDate.forEach(function(v, k) {
            weeks.push(v.month + '/' + v.day + '/' + v.year);
        });
```

[image]

How can I structure my query to get week ranges for all records?

---

I've done this similar query (same query as above, without `dayOfMonth` and `week`) with months, and was able to get exactly what I wanted:

`$scope.monthlySummaries = res.data[0].distinctDate;`

[image]

---

**Note**: I originally simply wanted to grab `distinct` `ISO` dates of each record,

```
 db.mycollection.distinct('date', {}, {});
```

But this returned distinct dates by seconds, meaning it gives duplicates for days, sample output:

```
ISODate("2015-10-13T15:44:31.944Z"),
ISODate("2015-10-13T16:52:03.830Z"),
ISODate("2015-10-13T17:18:25.798Z"),
ISODate("2015-10-13T17:24:47.881Z")
```

Then I would simply format the times on the Frontend using `momentJS`:

```
var formattedDate = moment(data.date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
var weekNumber = moment(formattedDate, "MM-DD-YYYY").isoWeek();
```

Comment: Generally speaking image are not useful. users prefer to work with documents. How about editing your question to show us sample document with expected result?